# USB drives are not being recognized

Tags: usb-drive

To be specific, I cant access them.  Plugging in a USB drive (mouse and keyboard work fine) will cause it to register for a second, popping up in my files, and then completely disappear.  I have tried 3 different USB drives, all work on other computers, and they all show up temporally.  My USB ports are fine, and so are the drives, but I cannot seem to view there contents or add more.  I am new to ubuntu so it is probably a simple answer, but I need help.  All the guides in found where outdated.  If it matters I am using xfce on a low end laptop.

Edit:  I managed to click on the drive before it disapered, it told me it "Failed to mount 16 GB Volume"  "Not authorized to perform operation"  I am the only one with access to this, there is no one who has higher authorization.

Edit 2:  I looked up similar problems and have learned it's name (/dev/sda) created a separate directory (/media/usb)  and attempted to manually mount it with "sudo mount /dev/sda /media/usb"  It told me that either "/dev/sda is already mounted" or "/media/usb is busy"  I then ran the command "sudo umount /media/usb" and "sudo umount /dev/sda" only to learn that both are out of use.... please help me.  I have hit a wall.

Comment: Look at the logs! In a terminal window, `journalctl --follow` and plug in your USB drive.

Comment: It said "No journal files were found".   I plugged the USB in after using the command, and tried using the command while it was plugged in.

Comment: You can try `tail -f /var/log/syslog` is an alternative.

Comment: Large external USB drives normally can not be powered by the USB port by itself, and require the use of an external AC power supply for the external drive, or the use of a powered USB hub. Also, make sure that you're plugging USB 3.x drives into USB 3.x ports.

Comment: The drive is pretty small, 16 GB, and is in the right port (I think)  I recently learned it is a problem with permissions, I am not authorized to use external drives.  Know how to change it?  guides i found are outdated.